# Store method with its parameter values?

Tags: java, function

I've a java function like

```
String abc="myvalue";
myfunction(String abc);
```

Is there any possibility to store this myfucntion("myvalue"); in an object to recall it automatically?

**Explanation:**

I've a function with many parameters values may 20-30, my application is being auto-starting when windows is login.

Once user launched the function first time I need to store that function with is passed values for each parameter. So that when an application will be auto-start it can recall that function from its storing place.

Comment: First of all, your method needs to be redesigned: 20 parameters for a method is way too much. Java has classes. Group parameters into objects, and make your method take only a few parameters. Second: what you actually need to do is to save, on the file system, some document (in JSON or XML format, for example), containing the data that needs to be processed when your program starts up. Java has many ways of writing/reading structured data like JSON or XML.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you could do that using reflection. But that would be well, madness.

You do not store method invocations.

You store **data**.

You carefully decide who to slice information into reasonable "records", and then you store that data using a decent format, for example JSON or XML. You define a configuration object for example, and then you store the information in that object. And later on, that information is loaded from disk, and then you *apply* that.